# Forcing https in .htaccess conflicting with URL rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess

here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

At this moment what is happening is the following:

```
http://somesubdomain.mydomain.com/param1/param2
```

is redirected to:

```
https://somesubdomain.mydomain.com/index.php?params=param1/param2
```

Obviously I want it to be redirected to

```
https://somesubdomain.mydomain.com/param1/param2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Changing the order solved the problem:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [L,QSA]
```